# Issue with related entity collection in Entity Framework 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have below four Entity in my project.

student

```
public int StudentID { get; set; }
public string StudentName { get; set; }
public int StandardId { get; set; }

public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
```

Teacher

```
public int TeacherId { get; set; }
public string TeacherName { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> StandardId { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
```

Standard

```
public int StandardId { get; set; }
public string StandardName { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
```

Course

```
public int CourseId { get; set; }
public string CourseName { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public int TeacherId { get; set; }

public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

If I try to directly access the list of courses from the student entity, I am always getting the count of courses as Zero.

```
   using (SchoolDBEntities db = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {
        var query = (from s in db.Students
                     select s).FirstOrDefault<Student>();

        foreach (var item in query.Courses)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(item.CourseName);                    
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But If I access the courses list like below, I am getting the data properly, What is the issue in first approach? Am I missing anything? I hope the below one is not a efficient way to access the data.

```
    using (SchoolDBEntities db = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {
        var query =   (from s in db.Students                               
                         select s).FirstOrDefault<Student>();

        foreach (var item in query.Standard.Teachers)
        {
            foreach (var crs in item.Courses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(crs.CourseName);
            }
        }                
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure your relationships are too clear, the standard part is confusing, can you elaborate a little more into the relationships you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to take a closer look later, but I would suggest that you have to use an include statement in your query. SchoolDBEntitites queries for students and doesn't load any teacher entities.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your student has courses? Do a SQL query to make sure that the data is there. Dumb question but have to ask...